# Graph of two-dimensional Gaussian beam

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to build a two-dimensional Gaussian beam `e^(-x^2)` using matplotlib.

I need to get:
[image]

Comment: Welcome in Stackoverflow. We’d love to help you. 
To get a good Answer for your Question: Can you edit the question and provide 
some code and/or more explanations, if there is, of what 
you are doing, and what's wrong. To avoid downvote and bad comments, 
please take some time to read Help: https://stackoverflow.com/help
 and How do I ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `np.meshgrid` to construct your
two-dimensional function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 250)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 250)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

zz = np.exp(-(xx**2 + yy**2))

plt.imshow(zz)
plt.show()
```